# Can't set DailyRollingFileAppender appender

Tags: log4j2, slf4j

Java 1.8

In my maven project I use `org.slf4j.Logger`

In `main/resourcse/log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test"
               status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Nice. It's work fine. It show output in console.

Now I want to save log to file with appender: `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`

I try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test"
               status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <appender name="File" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <param name="File" value="logs/trace.log"/>
            <param name="Append" value="true"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <!-- l, L, M - is extremely slow. It's use should be avoided unless execution
                    speed is not an issue. -->
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} %l %p:%n    %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But get error:

```
2021-11-26 22:31:32,693 main ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "appender"
2021-11-26 22:31:32,703 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "File" for logger config "root"
```

Comment: I guess, the appender, you would like to use is from log4j, but you are using log4j2. Most probably, you should have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882982/in-log4j-1-2-to-log4j-2-migration-what-to-do-with-the-dailyrollingfileappender

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In log4j 1.2 to log4j 2 migration, what to do with the DailyRollingFileAppender class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882982/in-log4j-1-2-to-log4j-2-migration-what-to-do-with-the-dailyrollingfileappender)